# End page after images, images appear in new page

Tags: graphics, page-breaking

So I'm making a progress report, and I want to include some graphs like so:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6 cm]{la_cuarta.png} \\
\end{center}
```

All images fit in the page, life is good, I want to start a new section where I explain the conclusions and add the bibliography, besides, there's not enough space left in the page.

But then tragedy strikes because no matter what I use, be it `\break` `\pagebreak` `\clearpage` `\doubleclearpage` or anything I can find that starts a new page the result is always the same:
The last graph appears in the new page while the two previous images get super separated to compensate the lack of the other and fill the page.

And yes, I am trying to end the page AFTER the graphs, I checked several times.

I even tried filling the remaining space on the page with white text but as soon as it is enough text to start another page the last graph goes to the next page too.

This has broken me, I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: try "enlarging" the page with the graphics, using `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` in the input between the first two graphics.  and then use `\newpage` after the third.  also, `\begin{center}` adds space above and below that environment, and it may just put the total over the default page length.

Comment: You people are magic, it does exactly what I wanted... but how?, I don't understand, could you explain to me what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

although this would have been a better question with a complete compilable
example, it's still possible to explain what is happening.

you are probably measuring and adding the exact vertical dimensions of your graphs.
however, you are inserting them using the `center` environment.  this environment
adds space at the top and the bottom of the environment, and these spaces are
cumulative.

the space at the top is the total of `\parskip` and `\parsep`, which are set in
the document class (which you haven't identified), and at the bottom, another
`\parskip`.

if you have left blank lines between the `center` environments, each one adds yet another `\parskip`.

in most document classes, `\parskip` usually includes a bit of shrink, but if the
total height of the three graphhs plus the vertical space (less allowable
shrink) exceeds the specified page height, the last object (here the third graph)
will be pushed to the next page.

since the measured height of just the graphs is less than the page height, and
there isn't any text on the page, it is likely that enlarging the page by a small
amount will allow all three figures to fit.  `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip)`
is an amount that is likely to be enough to accommodate the extra spaces between
the figures.

`\enlargethispage` *must* be present within the scope of what latex will put on
the affected page, hence the suggestion to insert it between the first two graphs.
`\newpage` following the third graph will force the page break where it is wanted,
and if the amount of the enlargement was guessed well, the page will be set as
you want it with the three graphs.